# How to swipe the listview -- android

Tags: android, performance

How to swipe using Motion Event. I have customized list view with edittext and checkedBox. I used to swipe the particular item of listview using setOnTouchListener.

```
** switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        //  mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow((IBinder) textView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

                   //   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus()    .getWindowToken(), 0);
                        float delta = motionEvent.getRawX();
                     float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
                                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                                    // A swipe occurred, do something
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }


                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            break;

                 }
                return false;
            }**
```

by using this code, i cant able to get the swipe action. Can anyone guide me on how to swipe the listview with editText

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) example.

It is nicely and well explained demo which might be useful and solve your problem ..

Answer (score 0):

i used the following code to detect aswipe on my listview row

```
public class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 2000;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            System.out.println("flingggggggggg");
            // mSlideoutHelper.close();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You will to override more methods to get it ready.

```
final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    yourListview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps you.